# Yii 2.0 Max Queries

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2

So, I'm running Yii 2.0.48 on PHP 8.1.20 on a Windows Server using IIS.  I'm accessing SQL Server using NTS drivers.  All is going well, except the Yii debug toolbar shows SQL queries are erroring (number is in red), even though the queries are executing.  The message is "Executed 1 database queries which took 60 ms.  Too many queries, allowed count is ."   Since the queries ARE executing, this is more of a nuisance than a problem, but curious if anyone else has experienced this problem.

Initially experienced with PHP 8.2, which I found is not supported by Yii.  Reverted to 8.1.

Comment: @samdark already answered to you https://forum.yiiframework.com/t/debug-toolbar-too-many-queries/135388

Comment: A fix has been released. Updating the package fixed it for me